# What type of component is this?

Tags: identification

I’m attempting to identify this component, internally consisting of two diodes, a resistor, transistor, and some sort of contact arm above the core of a solenoid/inductor… it has four pins externally, labeled 7, 8, 1, 14, a sticker that says DC 6V, and the entire package is about 2cm x 1.5 cm.

[image: external]

[image: external 2]

[image: internal 1]

[image: internal 2]

[image: internal 3]

Comment: For best results, it is useful to let us know from what unit this component was removed.

Comment: These weren’t removed from a unit… I found a 15 pc. lot in a high school physics storage closet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess it is an electromechanical buzzer, with the transistor and top contact forming the switching circuit for DC operation.

The top of the case is also suggestive, because it looks like the operating lever might strike the depressed plastic section, possibly acting like a sounding board.

Comment: Most PCB mount buzzers look almost identical from the PCB pin side, this just has 4 pins and most buzzers I found had 2 pins.

Comment: Agree that most have 2 pins, but it is possible it has additional control via extra pins, or they could just be to aid mounting.  A close up of the PCB might allow determination of the circuit/function.

Overall it looks for cheap construction, which to my mind adds to the buzzer/vibrator idea,